# Rails 3.2 asset pipeline issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a JS file defined in the app - `app/assets/javascripts/client/some-client.js.coffee`

In my dev env I can access this file via URL - `/assets/client/some-client.js`

But I cannot do the same in production? ...meaning the URL does not work, what could be wrong?

Comment: What files are in your public/assets directory on your production server?

Comment: Are you using Chrome to inspect for any javascript errors?  If so, is it giving you a 404 resource not found or something else?

Answer (score 3):

In prod, you will have access only to precompiled files, if you use the default configuration.

You can define which assets to precompile in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( some-client.js blabla.js some-client.css ) #etc...
```

Run `rake assets:precompile` to... precompile your assets.

Learn more with this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: So i added config.assets.precompile += %( some-client.js ) and tried accessing the file via "/assets/some-client.js" but it did not work

Comment: Are you using the Rails Javascript helper method?

Comment: Did you run `rake assets:precompile`? (if it still does not work, you might want to try to add `client/some-client.js` in your config instead of just `some-client.js`, not sure)

Comment: In any case, you should take the time to read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find it yet, be sure that you are accessing it through <%= javascript_include_tag "some-client" %>. As the asset pipeline handles finding where it has precompiled the asset. Along with the config.assets.precomile += %( some-client.js ). Also, if the helper function can't find that in production you might want to try moving client/ to assets/javascript/client I think it looks for assets for example javascripts files in app/assets/javascripts/ lib/assets/javascripts/ and vendor/assets/javascripts/ if I understand the asset pipeline. And it looks like you don't have it in any of those files, so it may be skipping it since it doesn't see it.

EDIT:

Looks like you have it in javascripts/ sorry. The asset pipeline should traverse subdirectories.